# A female crocodile may/can lay 30-40 eggs

Tags: modal-verbs

1. A female crocodile **may**  lay 30-40 eggs.
2. A female crocodile **can** lay 30-40 eggs.

Q1) What is the difference between (1) and (2)?

Q2) Can I replace "may" with "might" or "could" in (1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way of expressing this would be to say:

> A female crocodile may lay 30-40 eggs.

This construction is typically used to express the number of eggs that female crocodiles generally lay.

> A female crocodile can lay 30-40 eggs.

This expresses the maximum number of eggs that female crocodiles may lay.

In practice, both constructions are widely used interchangeably.

To replace **may** with **might** or **could** implies some condition or restriction to follow, or a reference to past conditions, eg:

> A female crocodile might lay 30-40 eggs **if conditions were ideal**.

> A female crocodile could lay 30-40 eggs in the soft beach sand that was found in the area before it was developed.

It's not grammatically wrong to use **might** or **could** but they would generally require particular contexts to justify their usage.